# How do you reuse (inherit) a form in JavaFX?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, javafx

I'm creating a type of calculator in JavaFX and I want to create a base form that each screen will inherit and extend.  The problem is that when I try this the old fashioned way, by extending the parent class in the child class definition, it doesn't actually reproduce my form with the components.

Say I have a scene with a label, textfield, and button, and a property variable, and I want to build three other scenes, as separate forms based on this generic base form, how do I do this?

Comment: If you could post code it will help.

Comment: And be careful: trying to do **reuse** by **inheritance** is often the wrong way. There is a reason why folks tell you to *favor composition over inheritance*.

Comment: You seriously need to provide a code example and accept the best answer that helps ya. You've asked **6** questions so far and accepted none!